# wordpress featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm new to Wordpress and I'm trying to create a new theme for it. I've downloaded the latest version (3.2.1) and installed it successfuly. But when I install my wordpress theme (to start to add the PHP) and try to create a new post, what happens is that the Set Featured Image box disappears and it only shows again when I return to the default theme.

Any suggestions for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple form of the featured images (post thumbnails) looks like this:

You need to have this piece of code in your functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Then in the index.php, or any other template file you want to show the post thumb or featured images, you would add this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

The code above usually goes just after <`?php the_title(); ?>`

Once you've added those, you should see them on posts. To have them on posts and pages, use this in place of the first code for the functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
```

Comment: Duplicate Post, Duplicate User?